# spring batch and Multi-threaded step

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am currently working on a Batch that consumes data from a large SQL database with millions of rows.

It does some processing in the processor that consists of grouping rows retrieved from the Reader via a large sql query with joins.

And the Writer writes the result to another table.

The problem is that this Batch has performance problems, because the Sql selection queries take a lot of time and the steps are not executed in multithreading.

So I'd like to run them in multitheading but the problem is that the steps group the rows by calculating a total amount of all the rows with the same types for example.

So if I put it in multitheading how can I do that when each partition is going to be processed in a different thread knowing that it's millions of rows that I can't store in the context to retrieve them after the step and do the grouping.
and I can't save them in the database either since it's millions of rows
Do you have any idea how I can do this?
I hope I was able to explain my problem well.
And thanks in advance for your help

Comment: This is basically a fork/join requirement, and can be implemented with a (remotely) partitioned step. Results can be aggregated with a `StepExecutionAggregator`. I shared a sample of how to do that [here](https://github.com/fmbenhassine/spring-batch-lab/tree/main/issues/so53366710). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar task like yours, unlikly we were using java 1.7 and spring 3.x. I can provide a configuiration in xml so maybe you will be able to use annotation configuration for this I've not tryed.

```
<batch:job id="dualAgeRestrictionJob">
    <-- use a listner if you need -->
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="dualAgeRestrictionJobListener" />
    </batch:listeners>
    <!-- master step, 10 threads (grid-size) -->
    <batch:step id="dualMasterStep">
        <partition step="dualSlaveStep"
            partitioner="arInputRangePartitioner">
            <handler grid-size="${AR_GRID_SIZE}" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
        </partition>
    </batch:step>   
</batch:job>
<-- here you define your reader processor and writer and the commit interval -->
<batch:step id="dualSlaveStep">
    <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <batch:chunk reader="arInputPagingItemReader"
            writer="arOutputWriter" processor="arInputItemProcessor"
            commit-interval="${AR_COMMIT_INTERVAL}" />
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>
<!-- The partitioner -->
<bean id="arInputRangePartitioner" class="com.example.ArInputRangePartitioner">
    <property name="arInputDao" ref="arInputJDBCTemplate" />
    <property name="statsForMail" ref="statsForMail" />
</bean>
<bean id="taskExecutor"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="${AR_CORE_POOL_SIZE}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${AR_MAX_POOL_SIZE}" />
    <property name="allowCoreThreadTimeOut" value="${AR_ALLOW_CORE_THREAD_TIME_OUT}" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="kvrDatasource" />
</bean>
```

The partitioner makes a query to count the rows and make chunks for each thread:

```
public class ArInputRangePartitioner implements Partitioner {
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ArInputRangePartitioner.class);

    private ArInputDao arInputDao;
    
    private StatsForMail statsForMail;

    @Override
    public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
        Map<String, ExecutionContext> result = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();
        // You can make a query and then divede the from to for each thread
        Map<Integer,Integer> idMap = arInputDao.getOrderIdList();
        Integer countRow = idMap.size();
        statsForMail.setNumberOfRecords( countRow );  
        Integer range = countRow / gridSize;
        Integer remains = countRow % gridSize;
        int fromId = 1;
        int toId = range;
        for (int i = 1; i <= gridSize; i++) {
            ExecutionContext value = new ExecutionContext();
            if(i == gridSize) {
                toId += remains;
            }
            logger.info("\nStarting : Thread {}", i);
            logger.info("fromId : {}", idMap.get(fromId) );
            logger.info("toId : {}", idMap.get(toId) );
            value.putInt("fromId", idMap.get(fromId) );
            value.putInt("toId", idMap.get(toId) );
            value.putString("name", "Thread" + i);
            result.put("partition" + i, value);
            fromId = toId + 1;
            toId += range;
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    public ArInputDao getArInputDao() {
        return arInputDao;
    }

    public void setArInputDao(ArInputDao arInputDao) {
        this.arInputDao = arInputDao;
    }

    public StatsForMail getStatsForMail() {
        return statsForMail;
    }

    public void setStatsForMail(StatsForMail statsForMail) {
        this.statsForMail = statsForMail;
    }

}
```

This is the configuration for the reader and writer:

```
<bean id="arInputPagingItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader" scope="step" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="kvrDatasource" />
    <property name="queryProvider">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean" >
            <property name="dataSource" ref="kvrDatasource" />
            <property name="selectClause" value="${AR_INPUT_PAGING_ITEM_READER_SELECT}" />
            <property name="fromClause" value="${AR_INPUT_PAGING_ITEM_READER_FROM}" />          <property name="whereClause" value="${AR_INPUT_PAGING_ITEM_READER_WHERE}" />
            <property name="sortKey" value="${AR_INPUT_PAGING_ITEM_READER_SORT}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <!-- Inject via the ExecutionContext in rangePartitioner -->
    <property name="parameterValues">
        <map>
            <entry key="fromId" value="#{stepExecutionContext[fromId]}" />
            <entry key="toId" value="#{stepExecutionContext[toId]}" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="pageSize" value="${AR_PAGE_SIZE}" />
    <property name="rowMapper" ref="arOutInRowMapper" />
</bean>
<bean id="arOutputWriter"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter"
        scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="kvrDatasource" />
    <property name="sql" value="${SQL_AR_OUTPUT_INSERT}"/>
    <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Maybe some one knows how to convert this with modern spring-batch/spring-boot

PS: Don't use a lot of thread otherwise spring batch will lose a lot of time to fill it's own tables. You have to make some benchmark to understand the correct configuration

I also suggest to not use jpa/hibernate with millions of rows, in my case I’ve used jdbcTemplate

**EDIT** for annotation configuration see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73514579/spring-batch-partitioned-step-duplicated-processing/73515255?noredirect=1#comment129826750_73515255)

Follow an example of configuration with partitioner

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JobConfig {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobConfig.class);

    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Value(value = "classpath:employees.csv")
    private Resource resource;

    @Bean("MyJob1")
    public Job createJob(@Qualifier("MyStep1") Step stepMaster) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("MyJob1")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(stepMaster)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean("MyStep1")
    public Step step(PartitionHandler partitionHandler, Partitioner partitioner) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("MyStep1")
            .partitioner("slaveStep", partitioner)
            .partitionHandler(partitionHandler)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean("slaveStep")
    public Step slaveStep(FlatFileItemReader<Employee> reader) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("slaveStep")
            .<Employee, Employee>chunk(1)
            .reader(reader)
            .processor((ItemProcessor<Employee, Employee>) employee -> {
                System.out.printf("Processed item %s%n", employee.getId());
                return employee;
            })
            .writer(list -> {
                for (Employee item : list) {
                    System.out.println(item);
                }
            })
            .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Partitioner partitioner() {
        return gridSize -> {
            Map<String, ExecutionContext> result = new HashMap<>();
            int lines = 0;
            try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream()))) {
                while (reader.readLine() != null) lines++;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            int range = lines / gridSize;
            int remains = lines % gridSize;
            int fromLine = 0;
            int toLine = range;
            for (int i = 1; i <= gridSize; i++) {
                if(i == gridSize) {
                    toLine += remains;
                }
                ExecutionContext value = new ExecutionContext();
                value.putInt("fromLine", fromLine);
                value.putInt("toLine", toLine);
                fromLine = toLine;
                toLine += range;
                result.put("partition" + i, value);
            }
            return result;
        };
    }
        

    @StepScope
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Employee> flatFileItemReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fromLine']}") int startLine, @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['toLine']}") int lastLine) {
        FlatFileItemReader<Employee> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(resource);

        DefaultLineMapper<Employee> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSet -> {
            String[] values = fieldSet.getValues();
            return Employee.builder()
                    .id(Integer.parseInt(values[0]))
                    .firstName(values[1])
                    .build();
        });

        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer(";"));
        reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
        reader.setCurrentItemCount(startLine);
        reader.setMaxItemCount(lastLine);

        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public PartitionHandler partitionHandler(@Qualifier("slaveStep") Step step, TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
        TaskExecutorPartitionHandler taskExecutorPartitionHandler = new TaskExecutorPartitionHandler();

        taskExecutorPartitionHandler.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
        taskExecutorPartitionHandler.setStep(step);
        taskExecutorPartitionHandler.setGridSize(5);

        return taskExecutorPartitionHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(5);
        taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return taskExecutor;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my questions.
If I understand correctly, so in the Partitioner, I have to run my selection query (which retrieves the millions of rows) and then I build the partitions according to my grouping criteria to have homogeneous partitions. This allows me to make my step after in partitions or multitheading?
If it's the case, isn't it going to be a problem, in terms of execution time, to group the millions of rows in the partitioner?
PS: I am also in XML configuration, and I have an oracle database.

Comment: The partitioner should only instruct the reader what data it should fetch in my case I’m dividing the input by id range. You have to find a way in the partitioner to instruct the reader on how to fetch the data. A good starting point is [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-batch-partitioner)

Comment: Now that I see my partitioner after years I’ve implemented a poor logic for partitioning I can only select the minimum id and use it as offset without using a Map :) Also I should use Long for the id. I have to fix it. Anyway you can also use a custom reader maybe implementing some spring class. Your have not telling us the query you are making in the reader. If you can try to make an example you can have better support

Comment: I’ve re read the documentation you can launch also steps in parallel instead of partitioning take a look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/scalability.html) at Parallel Steps paragraph. So you can have n readers and n steps that will group the input based on your logic. It all depends on what you have to do.

Comment: +1 to this answer and to using a partitioned step for this use case. This is basically a fork/join requirement, and I shared a sample of how to do that [here](https://github.com/fmbenhassine/spring-batch-lab/tree/main/issues/so53366710). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @MahmoudBenHassine for share the annotation configuration, my configuration is a little bit outdated. If you want please edit my answer to show the configuration with annotation

Comment: Thank you Pp88 for your answers i will try to make example of my query.
Mahmoud Ben Hassine I find the example you gave is interesting. Do you have an xml cofiguration example preferably of a partitioning step with a StepExecutionAggregator which groups the partitions after the step processing.
Basically, what I want is to make a select query that retrieves millions of rows that will then be mapped into objects, have them processed in a partitioned step, grouped by type in an aggregator and finally in the writer saving in the database the final result of all the grouped rows.

Comment: I repeat myself you can’t do one query that retrieves millions of rows in one round. You have to at the minimum paging the query. If you post an example we can understand better. Every partition has it’s reader yes it is the same but the Partitioner will give the reader some params to partition the input.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar use case where I had to start off with reading millions of records based on certain criteria as input from a rest endpoint and process it parallelly using 20-30 threads to meet extreme deadlines. But subsequent challenges were that same complex queries were made to database and then partitioned to be shared across generated threads.

- Better solution:
  We solved it by reading the data once and then internally partition it and pass it to threads initiated.

A typical batch process would have the objective -> to read, make some http calls/ manipulate the data, and write it to a response log table.

Spring batch provides the capability to keep track of the records processed so that a restart can be initiated to pick up the remaining lot to process. An alternative to this can be a flag in your master table to mark the record as processed so it need not be picked during restart.

Multiple challenges faced were :

- support of joins in the query reader
- partitioning of data.
- same record being processed again

---

- Coming to multi processing ->

Lets say you have 10000 records and you need to process 5 records parallelly.

Multiple creative solutions can be implemented but the two most often used that fit all use cases would be

- partitioning data on no of records.
- partitioning data on the mod of value of index data if numeric.

Considering the memory the machine will be able to serve, a suitable number of threads can be selected. Eg 5. => 10000/5 => each thread would process 2000 records.

Partitioning is a processing to split the ranges and allowing each step execution process to pick it in its own thread and run it. For the above step we will need to split those ranges and pass it while query execution to make it fetch records for the range and continue the process in a separate thread.

- Thread 0 : 1–2000
- Thread 1 : 2001–4000
- Thread 2 : 4001–6000
- Thread 3 : 6001–8000
- Thread 4 : 8001–10000

Another logic for partitioning would be assigning the threads 0 to 4 and query basis the modulo of the number. But one drawback of this could be that one particular range would receive more load compared to others whereas the previous approach would ensure that everyone gets a fair share.

The split data is passed on to the separate thread which will start processing it and write data at the commit interval ( chunk size ) mentioned in the step.

---

Code :

- READER

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public JdbcPagingItemReader<YourDataType> dataReaders(
    @Value("#{jobParameters[param1]}") final String param1, 
    @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['modulo']}") Long modulo) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Thread started reading for modulo index : " + modulo);
    JdbcPagingItemReader<YourDataType> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader <> ();
    reader.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    reader.setRowMapper(new YourDataTypeRowMapper());
    reader.setQueryProvider(queryProvider(param1, modulo));
    return reader;

public OraclePagingQueryProvider queryProvider(String param1, Long modulo) throws Exception {
    OraclePagingQueryProvider provider = new OraclePagingQueryProvider();
    provider.setSelectclause("your elements to query");
    provider.setFromClause("your tables/ joined tables");
    provider.setWhereclause("where clauses AND MOD (TO_NUMBER(yourkey) = " + modulo);
    Map<String,Order> sortkeys = new HashMap<>();
    sortKeys.put("yoursortkey", Order.ASCENDING);
    provider.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
    return provider;
}
```

Sample data reader -> param1 is any parameter that user would want to input. modulo is a step execution parameter — passed from the Partitioner object.

Paritioner object if to be used for modulo 5 would have modulo 0|1|2|3|4 and this would spawn 5 threads which would interact with the reader and fetch data for the divided sets.

---

- WRITER

```
@Bean
public JdbcbatchItemWriter<YourDataType> dataWriter() throws Exception {
    logger.info("Initializing data writer"); 
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<YourDataType> databaseItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>(); 
    databaseItemWriter.setDataSource(injectyourdatasourcehere); 
    databaseItemWriter.setsql(INSERT_QUERY_HERE); 
    ItemPreparedStatementsetter<RespData> ps = new YourResponsePreparedStatement(); 
    databaseItemWriter.setItemPreparedStatementsetter(ps); 
    return databaseItemWriter;
}

public class Your ResponsePreparedStatement implements ItemPreparedStatementSetter<RespData> {
    public void setValues (RespData respData, PreparedStatement preparedStatement)throws SQLException {
        preparedStatement.setString(1, respData.getYourData());
    }
}
```

Response Writer to log response to any table to keep tab of the processed data for analytics or business reporting.

---

- PROCESSOR

```
@Bean 
public ItemProcessor<YourDataType,RespData> processor() {

   return new YOURProcessor();

}
```

Processor where the core logic for the data manipulation would be written. Response returned is of the type which is expected by the Data writer.

---

- If you wish to skip spring batch tables auto creation, overriding batch configuration would solve the issue.

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    public class BatchConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {}
    }
```

else such an exception could be encountered:

> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]Caused by:
> org.springframework.dao.CannotSerializeTransactionException:
> PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into
> BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values
> (?, ?, ?, ?)]; ORA-08177: can’t serialize access for this transaction
> ; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08177: can’t
> serialize access for this transaction

---

Column Range partitioner can be created as:

```
@Component 
public class ColumnRangePartitioner implements Partitioner { 
Map<String,ExecutionContext> result = new HashMap(); 

@Override 
public Map<String,ExecutionContext> partition(int gridsize) {
    Map<String,ExecutionContext> result = new HashMap<>(); 
     int start = 0; 
     while (start < gridSize) { 
     ExecutionContext value = new ExecutionContext(); 
     result.put("partition : " + start, value);
     value.putInt("modulo", start); 
     start += 1;
   }
  return result;
 }
}
```

- Setting up of job and step

our job will be focusing on executing step1 — which will spawn threads based on the partitioner provided — here columnrange partitioner — to process the step.

Grid size is the no of parallel threads ( modulo to be calculated of using ).

Every processStep step is a series of reading the data for that specific thread assigned modulo, processing it and then writing it.

```
@Bean
public ColumnRangePartitioner getParitioner () throws Exception {
    ColumnRangePartitioner columnRangePartitioner = new ColumnRangePartitioner();
    return columnRangePartitioner;
}

@Bean
public Step step1(@Qualifier("processStep") Step processStep, 
                StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) throws Exception {
return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                         .listener(jobCompletionNotifier)
                         .partitioner(processStep.getName(),getParitioner())
                         .step(processStep)
                         .gridSize(parallelThreads)
                         .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                         .build();
}


@Bean
public Step processStep(
@Qualifier("DataReader") ItemReader<ReadType>  reader, 
@Qualifier("LogWRITE") ItemWriter<WriterType> writer, 
StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) throws Exception {
return stepBuilderFactory.get("processStep")
                        .<ReadType,WriterType> chunk(1)
                        .reader(reader)
                        .processor(processor())
                        .writer (writer)
                        .faultTolerant()
                        .skip(Exception.class)
                        .skipLimit(exceptionLimit)
                        .build();
 
}

@Bean
public SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    return asyncTaskExecutor;
}



@Bean
public Job our JOB (@Qualifier("step1") Step step1, JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory) throws Exception {
return jobBuilderFactory.get("ourjob")
                        .start(step1)
                        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                        .preventRestart()
                        .build();   
}
```

This might be an usual spring batch solution but would be applicable to every migration requirement involving commonly used SQL DB/ java based solutions.

---

- We did add customizations to the application

Avoid executing the join query again and then filtering. complex joins could impact database performance. Hence a better solution would be to fetch the data once and split it internally. Memory used by the application would be huge and the hashmap would be populated with all the data your query would fetch but java is capable of handling that. That fetched data could be passed to the ListItemReader to process list of data for that particular thread parallelly.

For processing parallel requests ( not threads but parallel api calls to this application ) modification can be made to process a certain query once only keeping a lock on it using a semaphore so that other threads are waiting on it. Once lock is release those waiting threads would find that data to be present and db will not be queries again.

The code would for the above impl would be complex for this blog scope. Feel free to ask if any use case is required by your application.

---

Would love to solve any issues regarding the same. Feel free to reach out to me(Akshay) at akshay.patell1702@gmail.com or my colleague(Sagar) at sagarnagdev61@gmail.com

Comment: "The code would for the above impl would be complex for this blog scope" - this really isn't a blog?

Comment: Its quite long i understand but would be really helpful to anyone with a similar use case.