# Spring-batch partitioned step duplicated processing

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have thousands of records to process using spring-batch and it takes too much time for our business requirement. The logic is simply to read a CSV file record by record and do the processing.

I want to parallelise the step execution to speed up batch processing. I think the best choice would be to partition the step and execute let's say 1-100 records in one thread, 101-200 in another and so on. But instead, every thread processes all of the records.

The same happens in this very simple example:

1. 10 rows in CSV file
2. 5 threads
3. Each should process 2 records
4. Instead each processes 10 records

```java
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JobConfig {
    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Value("classpath:employees.csv")
    private Resource resourceFile;

    @Bean("MyJob1")
    public Job createJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("my job 1")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(step())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean("MyStep1")
    public Step step() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("my step 1")
            .partitioner("my step 1", new SimplePartitioner())
            .partitionHandler(partitionHandler())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean("slaveStep")
    public Step slaveStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("read csv stream")
            .<Employee, Employee>chunk(1)
            .reader(flatFileItemReader())
            .processor((ItemProcessor<Employee, Employee>) employee -> {
                System.out.printf("Processed item %s%n", employee.getId());
                return employee;
            })
            .writer(list -> {
                for (Employee item : list) {
                    System.out.println(item);
                }
            })
            .build();
    }

    @StepScope
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Employee> flatFileItemReader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<Employee> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(resourceFile);

        DefaultLineMapper<Employee> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSet -> {
            String[] values = fieldSet.getValues();
            return Employee.builder()
                .id(Integer.parseInt(values[0]))
                .firstName(values[1])
                .build();
        });

        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer(";"));
        reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);

        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public PartitionHandler partitionHandler() {
        TaskExecutorPartitionHandler taskExecutorPartitionHandler = new TaskExecutorPartitionHandler();

        taskExecutorPartitionHandler.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
        taskExecutorPartitionHandler.setStep(slaveStep());
        taskExecutorPartitionHandler.setGridSize(5);

        return taskExecutorPartitionHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(5);
        taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return taskExecutor;
    }
}
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchTestsApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    private final JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    private final Job job;

    public SpringBatchTestsApplication(JobLauncher jobLauncher,
                                       @Qualifier("MyJob1") Job job) {
        this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
        this.job = job;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBatchTestsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }
}
```

```java
@Value
@Builder
public class Employee {
    private final int id;
    private final String firstName;
}
```

employees.csv:

```
1;Jakub
2;Mike
3;Pawel
4;Joana
5;Michal
6;Joe
7;Bailey
8;Bailhache
9;John
10;Eva
```

Example (example because the order is not important) expected output for 5 threads (gridSize):

```
Processed item 1
Employee(id=1, firstName=Jakub)
Processed item 2
Employee(id=2, firstName=Mike)
Processed item 3
Employee(id=3, firstName=Pawel)
Processed item 4
Employee(id=4, firstName=Joana)
Processed item 5
Employee(id=5, firstName=Michal)
Processed item 6
Employee(id=6, firstName=Joe)
Processed item 7
Employee(id=7, firstName=Bailey)
Processed item 8
Employee(id=8, firstName=Bailhache)
Processed item 9
Employee(id=9, firstName=John)
Processed item 10
Employee(id=10, firstName=Eva)
```

The actual output is that the above occurs 5 times.

Comment: What is `SimplePartitioner` It’s a class of spring? And you are not telling the reader witch line he should read. And I don’t know if you can instruct `FlatFileItemReader` to read only some lines of the file. Maybe you have to create your own reader and you should inject in it the lines you set in the `ExecutionContext` by the partitioner.

Comment: ```SimplePartitioner``` is spring's class.

Comment: Yes I see it, It doe's nothing...

Comment: Hmm, it assigns the ExecutionContext to the partition, so it does something. Later, you could extract the information about the partition in the reader using late binding (```@Value(#...)```) and decide if this line is supposed to be read by this or the other thread.

Comment: It only creates a map with `ExecutonContext` but it has noting ist in it to inject in the step, so it's useless

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether my solution is the best but it is worked.

I added two parameters as global in `JobConfig` class:

```
private int startLine = -1;
private int lastLine = 1;
```

Then I set these parameters to reader in `flatFileItemReader` method:

```
reader.setCurrentItemCount(startLine);
reader.setMaxItemCount(lastLine);
startLine+=2;
lastLine+=2;
```

All code:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JobConfig {
    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    private int startLine = -1;
    private int lastLine = 1;

    @Value("classpath:employees.csv")
    private Resource resourceFile;

    @Bean("MyJob1")
    public Job createJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("my job 1")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean("MyStep1")
    public Step step() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("my step 1")
                .partitioner("my step 1", new SimplePartitioner())
                .partitionHandler(partitionHandler())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean("slaveStep")
    public Step slaveStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("read csv stream")
                .<Employee, Employee>chunk(1)
                .reader(flatFileItemReader())
                .processor((ItemProcessor<Employee, Employee>) employee -> {
                    System.out.printf("Processed item %s%n", employee.getId());
                    return employee;
                })
                .writer(list -> {
                    for (Employee item : list) {
                        //System.out.println(item);
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }

    @StepScope
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Employee> flatFileItemReader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<Employee> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(resourceFile);

        DefaultLineMapper<Employee> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSet -> {
            String[] values = fieldSet.getValues();
            return Employee.builder()
                    .id(Integer.parseInt(values[0]))
                    .firstName(values[1])
                    .build();
        });

        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer(";"));
        reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
        reader.setCurrentItemCount(startLine);
        reader.setMaxItemCount(lastLine);
        startLine+=2;
        lastLine+=2;
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public PartitionHandler partitionHandler() {
        TaskExecutorPartitionHandler taskExecutorPartitionHandler = new TaskExecutorPartitionHandler();

        taskExecutorPartitionHandler.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
        taskExecutorPartitionHandler.setStep(slaveStep());
        taskExecutorPartitionHandler.setGridSize(5);

        return taskExecutorPartitionHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(5);
        taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return taskExecutor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope it’s partitioner job to do the partitioning. But you discover that he can use `FlatFileItemReader`

Comment: Cool thank you. Shouldn't ```startLine``` and ```lastLine``` be ```AtomicInteger``` to use ```getAndAdd(2)```? I'm worried about race conditions.

Comment: This is a wrong approach use the solution with the partitioner as I showed

Comment: I agree that it violates the Single Responsibility Principle. But apart from that why do you think this solution is incorrect?

Comment: because he is not using the partitioner at all, and as you said you can have race condition problems

Answer (score 1):

This should be the solution look at the partitioner he will take care of counting the lines of the file and divde them for the reader and the usage of `@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fromLine']}")` to inject in the reader the correct lines to read.

An please use injection instead of calling the methods.

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JobConfig {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobConfig.class);

    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Value(value = "classpath:employees.csv")
    private Resource resource;

    @Bean("MyJob1")
    public Job createJob(@Qualifier("MyStep1") Step stepMaster) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("MyJob1")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(stepMaster)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean("MyStep1")
    public Step step(PartitionHandler partitionHandler, Partitioner partitioner) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("MyStep1")
            .partitioner("slaveStep", partitioner)
            .partitionHandler(partitionHandler)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean("slaveStep")
    public Step slaveStep(FlatFileItemReader<Employee> reader) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("slaveStep")
            .<Employee, Employee>chunk(1)
            .reader(reader)
            .processor((ItemProcessor<Employee, Employee>) employee -> {
                System.out.printf("Processed item %s%n", employee.getId());
                return employee;
            })
            .writer(list -> {
                for (Employee item : list) {
                    System.out.println(item);
                }
            })
            .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Partitioner partitioner() {
        return gridSize -> {
            Map<String, ExecutionContext> result = new HashMap<>();
            int lines = 0;
            try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream()))) {
                while (reader.readLine() != null) lines++;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            int range = lines / gridSize;
            int remains = lines % gridSize;
            int fromLine = 0;
            int toLine = range;
            for (int i = 1; i <= gridSize; i++) {
                if(i == gridSize) {
                    toLine += remains;
                }
                ExecutionContext value = new ExecutionContext();
                value.putInt("fromLine", fromLine);
                value.putInt("toLine", toLine);
                fromLine = toLine;
                toLine += range;
                result.put("partition" + i, value);
            }
            return result;
        };
    }
        

    @StepScope
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Employee> flatFileItemReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fromLine']}") int startLine, @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['toLine']}") int lastLine) {
        FlatFileItemReader<Employee> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(resource);

        DefaultLineMapper<Employee> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSet -> {
            String[] values = fieldSet.getValues();
            return Employee.builder()
                    .id(Integer.parseInt(values[0]))
                    .firstName(values[1])
                    .build();
        });

        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer(";"));
        reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
        reader.setCurrentItemCount(startLine);
        reader.setMaxItemCount(lastLine);

        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public PartitionHandler partitionHandler(@Qualifier("slaveStep") Step step, TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
        TaskExecutorPartitionHandler taskExecutorPartitionHandler = new TaskExecutorPartitionHandler();

        taskExecutorPartitionHandler.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
        taskExecutorPartitionHandler.setStep(step);
        taskExecutorPartitionHandler.setGridSize(5);

        return taskExecutorPartitionHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(5);
        taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return taskExecutor;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works too. Maybe as an enhancement instead of reading the whole file to count the number of records, better would be to use modulo, so each thread reads every lineNumber % gridSize. And why do you prefer injection over calling the method?

Comment: look at `flatFileItemReader` method he needs two int to be called, if you use injection you can inject directly the reader in the method that needs it. If you call the method you have to pass the int also to the method that calls `flatFileItemReader`. How do you use the modulo without counting the lines?

Answer (score 0):

I think in principle my initial idea to partition reading from the CSV file is wrong. Partitioning is effective when it is easy to partition the resource from which the reading will be performed.

1. For example database table. Every thread would read the separate range of the records.
2. Several files. Every thread would read the separate file.

However, partitioning the file where one thread would read a specific range of the records will not necessarily mean any performance gain:
[Split one large file into multiple InputStream(s) to be processed in multithreading in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51566645/split-one-large-file-into-multiple-inputstreams-to-be-processed-in-multithread)

One-line improvement to employ several threads into batch processing would be to add `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`. Each chunk of items then is read, processed and written in a separate thread:

```java
@Bean("MyStep1")
public Step step() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("my step 1")
        .<Employee, Employee>chunk(1)
        .reader(flatFileItemReader())
        .processor((ItemProcessor<Employee, Employee>) employee -> {
            System.out.printf("Processed item %s%n", employee.getId());
            return employee;
        })
        .writer(list -> {
            for (Employee item : list) {
                System.out.println(item);
            }
        })
        .taskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("spring_batch"))
        .build();
}
```